# Use proxy in linux server. Different result between command line and browser execution

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, proxy, apache-virtualhost, cpanel

In my web server i am trying to use proxy in all outgoing http(s) request in  linux ( `centos7` ). example: `curl` request.

After set proxy by `export http_proxy and https_proxy`, when i run a file (php) or use `wget` or `curl` from command line, it uses proxy. But when from browser, it doesn't use proxy.

I am using `cpanel` so it has `apache` server.

Is it need to configure `apache` separately for proxy?

What i want is my web applications should use proxy for all outgoing request. example: `curl`

Comment: google-chrome respects http_proxy, just make sure you start it from the session where you export the http_proxy var, or its child session (the ones where wget and curl succeed would be a good choice, enter google-chrome command in your terminal window).
Browsers other than chrome may need to setup that in some settings.

Comment: You may be missed the point that i am using cpanel. I am working in  a web server with apache.
what i want that my web application's outgoing requests should use proxy

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I think it is anyway the matter of making process (curl/wget/php) have http_proxy var set in its environment, so you need php to have that. I am not familiar with cPanle, perhaps it has option of adding env vars to php process?

Comment: it is a good idea, let me check.

Comment: couldn't find anything. Even Apache's `ProxyRemote` also not working